# GitLab Pages API 404 error for certain projects

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, gitlab-pages

I have been writing automation scripts to generate and update SSL certificates using Namesilo, Letsencrypt and Gitlab APIs.
I almost got to the end, but I am getting a 404 error when trying to update the SSL certificate on Gitlab.

The weird part is that the error happens on only one of my two projects. Specifically, running:

```
curl --header "Private-Token: XXXXXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/pallavagarwal07%2Fshort-links/pages/domains/pallav.xyz"
```

works fine and fetches the details of domain `pallav.xyz` in project `short-links`.

But, running:

```
curl --header "Private-Token: XXXXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/pallavagarwal07%2Fpallavagarwal07.gitlab.io/pages/domains/varstack.com"
```

returns a 404 error. However, what makes it weirder is that if I remove the domain name `varstack.com` from the URL, it gives me the list of domains as expected:

```
curl --header "Private-Token: XXXXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/pallavagarwal07%2Fpallavagarwal07.gitlab.io/pages/domains"
```

returns:

```
[{"domain":"varstack.com","url":"https://varstack.com","certificate":....]
```

Comment: Can you check the permissions of the user? It may be related

Comment: @djuarez The user is the owner pallavagarwal07 in both cases. I am using the same token in all cases. Token is generated using the first priviledge "Full Read/Write API access".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out (although I would still classify this as a bug on the part of GitLab).

The ID needs to be url-encoded, which is why I had replaced `/` in the repository name by `%2F`. However the character `.` should not have been a problem (`-` in the former URL did not cause any problem). However, replacing `.` by `%2E` gives expected (correct) results.

I think this is a bug because:

1. This behavior is not documented (which characters are allowed?).
2. The URL without the domain name works flawlessly even without encoding `.`, including the API to add new domains (which also takes domain as a form parameter, and not in URL).

TL;DR

Using:

```
pallavagarwal07%2Fpallavagarwal07%2Egitlab%2Eio
```

instead of

```
pallavagarwal07%2Fpallavagarwal07.gitlab.io
```

in the URL makes it work.